# Problems with clustered DTC server 2008 R2 when failed over or restarted

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, clustering, msdtc

I had a working clustred DTC, but due to a disk migration, I had to delete the service and recreate it. Thats how the problem started.

When I recreate the service, it comes online perfectly. But when failed over or restarted, the service fails. Severname and Disk Drive resources comes online fine, but the DTC resource fails. I have set the dependencies for disk and name on the DTC resource.

As I said, when the service is created, it works fine, and I can see the service for clustred DTC on the active node. But when failed over or restarted, that service on the active node disappears.

Windows log says this:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering
Date:          5/26/2014 9:56:29 AM
Event ID:      1069
Task Category: Resource Control Manager
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      computer.domain.se
Description:
Cluster resource 'MSDTC-wfalitecl011Dtc' in clustered service or application 'wfalitecl011Dtc' failed.

Event XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering" Guid="{BAF908EA-3421-4CA9-9B84-6689B8C6F85F}" />
    <EventID>1069</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-05-26T07:56:29.209557400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>367173</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="8700" ThreadID="2464" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>computer.domain.se</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="ResourceName">MSDTC-wfalitecl011Dtc</Data>
    <Data Name="ResourceGroup">wfalitecl011Dtc</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

More Log:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering
Date:          5/26/2014 9:56:29 AM
Event ID:      1205
Task Category: Resource Control Manager
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      computer.domain.se
Description:
The Cluster service failed to bring clustered service or application 'wfalitecl011Dtc' completely online or offline. One or more resources may be in a failed state. This may impact the availability of the clustered service or application.

Event XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering" Guid="{BAF908EA-3421-4CA9-9B84-6689B8C6F85F}" />
    <EventID>1205</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-05-26T07:56:29.240758000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>367174</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="8700" ThreadID="5836" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>computer.domain.se</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="ResourceGroup">wfalitecl011Dtc</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

And more log:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-MSDTC Client 2
Date:          5/26/2014 8:48:13 AM
Event ID:      4879
Task Category: CM
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      domain.comoputer.se
Description:
MSDTC encountered an error (HR=0x80000171) while attempting to establish a secure connection with system WFALITECL011DTC.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-MSDTC Client 2" Guid="{155CB334-3D7F-4ff1-B107-DF8AFC3C0363}" EventSourceName="MSDTC Client 2" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">4879</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-05-26T06:48:13.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1766166</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>computer.domain.se</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">80000171</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">WFALITECL011DTC</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

This is found in the cluster.log:

```
000021fc.00000528::2014/05/26-07:53:12.196 WARN  [API] s_ApiOpenResourceEx: Resource aabda8c2-3771-4175-899a-0c28ca69bfa6 not found, status = 5007
```

I have tried deleting the AD computer account for this service, no difference. I have deleted and recreated the service a bunch of times but always the same result.

Does anyone have an idea on where to start looking?

Comment: I had the same issue. Can you create the service with a slightly different name?

Comment: I have tried changing the name, no luck.

Comment: Have you checked the services on each node to see if there is a DTC service with a GUID in the name? If so you should remove this service from each node. Then recreate the clustered role.

Comment: When i create the clustered resource, a service with a GUID is created, and running. But as soon as i restart the service or try to failover, that service disapears. As i said, when i create it, it is online and seems to be working.

Comment: It was a while ago i posted this, but in case anyone is intrested, we have solved it. It was caused by using Symantec Storage Foundation as Disk Managment. [link]http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH125163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a while i posted this, i did solve the problem after i while. The problem was related to Symantec Storage Foundation.

KB here: http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH125163

In the article it says you need to call them to get a hotfix, but SP2 that is avalible for download also solved the problem.